# Bound attribute empty in an angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, directive

I've a simple directive

```
'use strict';

angular.module('ludaooApp')
  .directive('rating', function () {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'app/rating/rating.html',
      restrict: 'EA',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.mark = attrs.mark;
          console.log(attrs);
    };
  })
```

This directive only log the attributes of the directive.

Here is how I use that directive :

```
<rating mark="{{game.rating}}" style="font-size: 30px"></rating>
```

And here is the result of the web inspector :

[image]

As you can see, mark is empty `mark=""` on the first line. But after, it is filled in with its value `mark="4.16"`.

The result is that if I `console.log(scope.mark)`, I see 0 instead of 4.16.

I think it's because the 4.16 is retrieved from the database and, the code is executed before that `{{game.rating}}` is initialized in the controller.

So the question is, how to deal with this problem ? And how to access to the "4.16" ?

Comment: 0 is the value of `game.rating` at the time of rendering the directive.But the value you find in dev console is the current value of mark evaluated after logging in the console. If you hover near the `i` you will find that message.

Comment: It's because you forgot to add `scope: { mark: '=' }` to your directive. Add it after `restrict: 'EA'` (although order doesn't matter).

Comment: you can use a `$watch` on the `mark` and check if value is greater than 0 and then do something like `console.log(value)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use angular promises in service, that receives data from api, and pass the state of deffered object to ng-if - this decision can help to set aside rendering of rating directive.

Simple example:

```
<div ng-app="ludaooApp">
  <div ng-controller="GameCtrl as game">
    <rating mark="{{game.rating}}" ng-if="game.$promise.status"></rating>
  </div>
</div>


 (function(angular){
   "use strict";

   angular.module('ludaooApp',[])
   .controller('GameCtrl', ['$timeout', '$q', function($timeout, $q){
        var game = this;
        var deferred = $q.defer()
        game.$promise = deferred.promise.$$state
        $timeout(function(){
            game.rating = 4.16;
            deferred.resolve();
        },3);    
    }])
    .directive('rating', function () {
       return {     
          restrict: 'EA',      
          link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
             scope.mark = scope.$eval(attrs.mark);
             console.log(attrs);
       }
      };
    })
 })(window.angular);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d_enver/o1pg47ro/)

Answer (score 1):

I think Enver's solution may work but it's over-complicated. The issue is caused by game.rating has not been completely bound when it's read. A more simple solution is to wait until binding of game.rating is completely done and assigned to mark attribute, as follows:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    attrs.$observe("mark", function(value) {
        // read "mark" here
        console.log(attrs.mark);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your directive is getting created before your `{{game.rating}}` has completed binding.

Try using `ngAttr` so that your attribute is defined only after the binding completes:

```
<rating ng-attr-mark="{{game.rating}}" style="font-size: 30px"></rating>
```

Comment: Have the same issue, got `undefined` this way.